# The meaning of "for" in "all I need is for..."

Tags: meaning, prepositions

There is a sentence in [Diary of a Wimpy Kid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diary_of_a_Wimpy_Kid): "Great. All I need is **for** some jerk to catch me carrying my book around and get the wrong idea".

I can't understand the meaning of **for**.

I've read a lot of explanations about this preposition but I can't understand why it is here. In this website there're at least two questions about this sentence but none of them about this preposition.

Comment: Thank you brother (if I can call you that)

Comment: The first question I ever asked on English Language Stack Exchange (which now has 45000+ views!) was about something similar, and the answers might be interesting to you: https://english.stackexchange.com/q/68669/21450

Comment: It's hard to explain "for" on its own, so I'll just explain the expression. "**All I need is for [X to happen]**" means the same thing as "I need [X to happen] and that's all I need." 

Of course, in this case, as is often the case with this expression, it is being used sarcastically. In its sarcastic usage, it means "It would be particularly bad if [X happened]."